# how to display the face strenght of normals?

Tags: interface, normals

I'm confused about what "normal face strength" is. I thought normals were just normalized 3D vectors that point to either side of a face, I didn't know they also had magnitude or "strength"value.

I know there is way to see which direction the normals are pointing by checking "Face Orientation" under the Overlay options but is there a way to also see what the strength of each normal is?

Also, is the normal strength of my meshes something that other programs can understand? For example, if I were to export my model as an OBJ and import it into Maya or Unity, will Maya know the strength of each normal?

By normal strength I mean this:
[image]

Comment: what are you exactly referring to? can you give examples? are you not confusing with normal or bump maps?

Comment: @moonboots Hi, I added a picture of what I mean by normal face strength

Comment: here is what the blender doc says: "For example, if three faces meet at a vertex and have the face weights weak, medium, and strong, then only the normal associated with the strong face will be used to set the final result." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html

Comment: @moonboots thanks, I did read that page before but couldn't find a way to display or know the normal stregth of a given face which is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: in your pop-up menu you can select by face strength but I guess you already know    ;)   sorry I don't know anything about this topic

Comment: Yes thanks, I did know about that but was wondering if there was a way to display it like you can display the direction of normals

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108002/discussion-between-jorge-luque-and-moonboots).